# Remove a specific direct share link from SharePoint Online or OneDrive

Tags: sharing, external-sharing

Last year Microsoft added the ability [to share files to anyone](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-OneDrive-Blog/Introducing-a-new-secure-external-sharing-experience/ba-p/112624), regardless if they have a Microsoft account or not.  These users will not show up in AzureAD as guest user accounts.  I am attempting to expire these cases of direct sharing links after 90 days since their last access.  I found the following example to remove all direct sharing links from a single item but have not yet found how to map which links go to which person.

```
Function Remove-OneDriveSharingLink {

param (   
       $OneDriveURL
   )   
process{

    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $OneDriveURL 
    $Ctx= Get-PnPContext


    $Files= Get-PnPListItem -List "documents"
    foreach( $File in $Files)
      {       
            $Froles= $File.RoleAssignments
            $Ctx.load($Froles)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            If($Froles.Count -gt 0)
            {

              for ($i = $Froles.Count -1; $i -ge 0 ; --$i)  
               {   
                  $Link=$Froles[$i].Member
                  $Ctx.Load($Link)
                  $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                  If($Link.title -like "SharingLinks*")
                  {
                   $Froles[$i].DeleteObject()
                  }
                  $Link = $null
               }  
              $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()           
             }      
      }

  }
  }

  Remove-OneDriveSharingLink -OneDriveURL "https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/alexw_tenantname_onmicrosoft_com"
```

I have written a script that queries the Audit log looking for `SecureLink` access, specifically I am querying on the operation `SecureLinkUsed`.  That gives me back all the uses of these types of links (includes all types of users, internal, guest user, and direct links).  I filter on `urn:spo:guest` to get the specific direct link uses to exclude internal and guest users.  The audit log contains truly useful information except that the `UniqueSharingId` is a blank GUID

**UniqueSharingId** 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

**ListItemUniqueId**    e7351249-95dd-41d2-b480-673ecb8582fa

**ObjectId**    https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myuser_mytenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/Share Test 3

**AuditEntryId**    https://mytenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myuser1_mytenant_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/Share Test 3|urn:spo:guest#myuser2@gmail.com

**Id**              ff42cedd-8cc5-4c06-dff9-08d614f86bb1

**UserIds**         urn:spo:guest#myuser2@gmail.com

**CreationTime**    2018-09-07T19:30:51

But unfortunately I don't get much information back when I get the SecureLink in PowerShell.  It looks like the `LoginName` and `Title` are configured in the following way:

`SharingLinks.ListItemGUID.Flexible.UniqueSharingID`

[image: SecureLinkInPowerShell]

Does anyone know of a way to find out to whom an external sharing link has been shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can determine the sharing information via a POST call to the `GetSharingInformation` REST API like so:

`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists(@a1)/GetItemById(@2)/GetSharingInformation?@a1='listguid'&@a2='itemID'&$Expand=permissionsInformation,pickerSettings`

The `linkMembers` object will give the username of the specific link.

[image]

[Found on the cann0n0nf0dder blog](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2018/04/04/externally-sharing-getsharinginformation-rest-api/).

Answer (score 0):

In response to:
Does anyone know of a way to find out to whom an external sharing link has been shared?

Try adding the following:

```
$Users=@(Get-PnPGroup -Identity $Link.title).Users
$User | Format-Table
```

Inside statement:

```
If($Link.title -like "SharingLinks*")
```